# Working Out Total Sales Using Comission Paid

Tags: percentages

If a sales agent earns 70% of the sale as comission. And his comission comes to 1400. What was the total value of sales?

I know the answer is 2000 (70% of 2000 is 1400) but assuming you don't have the information of 2000 how would you work it out?

Thank you

Comment: You divide.  $\frac {1400}{.7}=2000$.  But, more importantly, what firm does this fellow work for?  Are they hiring?

Answer (score 0):

Let us call the total amount of money earned from sales $S$. You say that 70% of the money earned from sales, that is, 70% of the amount $S$, he makes as commission. If we express 70% as a decimal, then we write
\begin{align}
0.70\cdot S&=1400\\
\Longrightarrow S&=\frac{1400}{0.70}\\
&=2000.
\end{align}